# Naming Convention: 2,4-dichlorophenylacetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

[image: Image of Structure]

Why is this the correct name for this compound? I understand the 2,4-dichloro part, but...

1. Why is it a phenol if there is no hydroxyl group directly bonded to the  hydrocarbon ring?
2. Why is it an **acetic** acid if it has a CH**2**COOH instead of a CH**3**COOH branch on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons passing understanding, a cyclic, aromatic, $\ce{C6H5}$ radical fragment (so a benzene minus one $\ce{H}$) is called "phenyl" for the purpose of nomenclature.

I doubt that "2,4-dichlorophenylacetic acid" is a truly IUPAC conforming name, so I'll outline the evolution of this name instead. First, there is acetic acid. You substitute one of the methyl $\ce{H}$s by phenyl: phenylacetic acid (tough to get nowadays, thanks to meth cookers). Now you substitute chlorine atoms for $\ce{H}$s on phenyl, voila.

*Note that substitution here is conceptual, not chemical - one would synthesize this very differently.*

Comment: I only had a brief flip through the Blue Book, but if I am not mistaken the PIN for this compound is probably (2,4-dichlorophenyl)acetic acid, as parentheses are required around compound substituents.